# How much to sue for something intangible not being met

Tags: canada, rental-property, damages, small-claims-court

In BC there is a right to [Quiet Enjoyment](http://www2.gov.bc.ca/gov/content/housing-tenancy/residential-tenancies/during-a-tenancy/quiet-enjoyment) which is at least partly the responsibility of the landlord. If a tenant was forced to move out due to Quiet Enjoyment not being fulfilled, how much would they seek in monetary compensation? Obviously I'm not asking for a specific number but how is such a number determined when going to court? The reason for moving out was the other roommates were doing drugs to the point where the entire house was hotboxed.

Comment: Probably same as any other time - damages of various kinds. How much did you have to spend to move vs. remaining? My understanding is that, under certain circumstances, you can even sue for more than what you lost - statutory damages, punitive damages, etc. For those I'd talk to a lawyer but for direct damages I'd check how much lighter your pocketbook is. If you don't have direct damages, why even sue?